# How can i recover old windows from window.old folder

Tags: windows, windows-xp

i got two windows folder in my c: the old one is called windows.old which contain windows xp and the other one is windows which is having window 7 is running currently.

I did install the windows 7 about an month ago and while installing it ask me to keep the old windows folder so i tick yes.

Now what i want to do is i want to run both windows xp and windows 7. Can it done with rename the windows to windows.old and windows.old to windows. will it be do the work?

Answer (score 0):

The windows.old folder contains the files from your previous Windows installation (in your case XP). If you need to retrieve data from that folder, read this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/where-are-my-files-and-folders-after-upgrading-from-windows-xp-or-windows-vista

Renaming those folders (Windows, Windows.old) will not work (and isn't even possible). If you want to run Windows 7 and Windows XP on one computer, you will have to use dual/multi boot. I suggest you read http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/install-multiple-operating-system-multiboot#1TC=windows-7 to set this up.